# How to build a DFA that recognizes a language

Tags: computability, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I have been given the following problem and was wondering if my solution is correct (taken from the textbook exercise in the book Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Martin Sipser):

Build a **DFA** that recognizes the following language knowing that `E = {0, 1}, {w | w is any string except 11 and 111}`.

My solution is:

[image]

Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: Does it recognize any string except for 11 and 111?

Comment: @user253751 yes that seems to be the question, to me the DFA looks fine!

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Initially build a finite automata of the language which generates only strings 11 and 111
And then by complementing the finite automata we will obtain the language which accepts all strings except 11 and 111
As we know that L(M)'=U-L(M)[image: you can check the finite automata here]